# Default Mac Ruby Gems?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks, ruby

A Mac always comes with some default ruby gems installed in the local RVM.

Is there anyway I can check or view a list of the default ruby gems installed in a Mac OSX Mavericks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Mavericks from AppStore.
Create another partition on your disk with Disk Utility (it is smart in resizing).
Install Mavericks on it and install XCode.
Then see what you got.